# Variable in for loop could not increment

Tags: python, macos, variables, pygame

This is part of a project concerning a shooting game. The variable `fail_times` is not increasing as it is supposed to. How should I handle this issue?

```
def check_fail(bullets,stats,screen,fail_times):   
        for bullet in bullets:  
            if bullet.rect.right>=screen.get_rect().right:  
                bullets.remove(bullet)    
                fail_times+=1    
                print(fail_times)    
            elif fail_times>3:
                stats.game_active=False   
                pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)
```

Comment: you mean: it doesn't increase from outside the function. That's expected. because integers are immutable. Return the value, and assign it back. Or use classes.

Comment: Don't modify something while you iterate over it. In particular you have `bullets.remove(bullet)` inside `for bullet in bullets`. This will lead to your loop behaving weirdly.

Comment: I also suspect you don't want to use `elif` - you probably want to run that body whenever `fail_times>3` regardless of the previous condition.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: no, i don't mean that. have you notice the ‘print(fail_times)' code? fail_times doesn't increment inside the function.

Comment: @AlexHall if i use `for bullet in bullets.copy()`, is it better?

Comment: Exactly, iterating over a copy is the most common solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a class with a class variable it'll have the scope you're looking for:

```
class game:
    def __init__(self, fail_times=0):
        self.fail_times = fail_times

    def check_fail(self, bullets, stats, screen):
        for bullet in bullets:
            if bullet.rect.right >= screen.get_rect().right:
                bullets.remove(bullet)
                self.fail_times += 1
                print(fail_times)
            elif fail_times > 3:
                stats.game_active = False
                pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)
```

Then to use it you have to instantiate the class:

```
my_game = game()
my_game.check_fail(bullets, stats, screen)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That's what i want!

Comment: Glad to hear it! Don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your issue ;)